# Can a TLS client perform any DH regeneration?

Tags: diffie-hellman

I have only the barest understanding of cryptography, but I've been following the Logjam issue; some posts and articles (elsewhere) imply that a client can regenerate DH keys. Is Logjam solely a server issue? Is there a way for the client to perform DH regeneration on a regular basis; if so, how? Is there any way the client can circumvent the Diffie-Hellman Logjam issue?

Comment: yes clients can trigger renegotiation - just cut the connection and reconnect. But you can't defeat Logjam that way because for this you'd need to re-negotiate the domain parameters used for DHE and they're expensive to calculate...

Answer (score 1):

A client can indeed "regenerate" DH-keys.
But this simply means he re-connects to the server. The Logjam attack works by recording the connection establishment and then compute the derived private key. For this attack to work the domain parameters of the DH-exchange need to remain unchanged as precomputation is neccessary. If you just reconnect the server will present you with the exact same group and the attack will only take seconds to decrypt the session key. For Logjam to be defeated one needs new domain parameters, which take a while to be generated, hence this isn't done on every connection, usually this isn't even done in *years*.

Logjam isn't solely a server issue. If the vulnerability is fixed on either the browser (how-to: next paragraph) or server-side it's closed. Both sides need to support it and all major browser companies (Mozilla, Google,...) already announced patches to close this vulnerability.

The client can circumvent the issue by *requiring* 2048-bit+ primes for the domain parameters of DH, if the client decides to use DH-exchange.
**The best way to avoid Logjam is to avoid DH, by choosing ECDH, which isn't vulnerable.
This is also the way recommend by the authors of the accomplying paper.**

Answer (score 0):

Logjam and FREAK differ only in a few minor details. Essentially, these are refinements of the old downgrade attack against SSLv2, allowing to play the same old trick with newer versions of the protocol.

The main issue is a TLS server can be tricked into using a weak key, be it RSA or DH. Then an attacker can break the weak key in such a short time that a MITM will not be noticed. (The MITM will recover the master secret before the TLS handshake times out and forge the MAC.)

TLS session keys are usually short lived (5 minutes). Forcing renegotiation will not help if the server reuses the same DH key. Even if it does not, generating new keys at a faster rate will increase the cost for an attacker by the same factor the cost is increased for the client and server.

In order to fix this, servers must stop issuing weak keys. This means export cipher suites are dead. They should have been removed from TLS implementations long ago.

As stated by SOJPM, clients should reject smaller keys, although, if the limit is set to 1024 bits or higher, this will certainly create issues with legacy software which does not support keys larger than 1024 bits.